# Brand new to C++ and a bit stuck on how to calculate a series product. (Instructions given below)

Tags: c++

Your program should prompt the user for two integers, for example m and n, then compute
and display the corresponding series product (the value of m × (m + 1) × (m + 2) × . . . ×
(n − 1) × n). In case you are confused, an example might be that user input 3 and 9. Then
you compute the product of 3 x 4 x 5 x 6 x 7 x 8 x 9.
It must be able to handle negative numbers and so far that isn't the problem but no matter how I input the code it will not return the product.

Below is what i have so far and I am sure it is pretty terrible for experienced coders but I'm assuming my error is in my "for" statement and any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, i;

    cout << "Input two integers separated by a blank space and press enter 
to display the corresponding series product.\n";
    cin >> a1 >> a2;

    if (a1 <= a2)
    {
        b1 = a1;
        b2 = a2;
    }
    else if (a2 <= a1)
    {
        b1 = a2;
        b2 = a1;
    }

    for (i =b1; i <= b2; i++)
    {
         a3 =* i;
    }

    cout << "The series product of "; cout << a1 << ", " << a2 << ", ";
    cout << " is: " << a3 << "\n" << endl;

     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: also the user must be allowed to enter the integers in any order (ie 2,5 or 5,2)

Comment: Please enter an examples covering all cases. E.g., if user enters 2, 5, what is the expected output and what do you see?

Comment: You never initialise a3. You should add `a3 = 1` somewhere before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few minor formatting errors. First off please don't make a new line when you are typing a string, as you have in your first statement. Also make sure the `cout` statements are one per line, to make it easier to read.

Rest of the code is fine however you do need to set up `a3 = 1` at start in order to have it multiply properly. Lastly you cannot do `a3 =* i;` it has to be `a3 *= i;`.

Fixed below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Set A3 = 1 here.
     int a1, a2, a3 = 1, b1, b2, i;

    cout << "Input two integers separated by a blank space and press enter to display the corresponding series product.\n";
    cin >> a1 >> a2;

    if (a1 <= a2)
    {
        b1 = a1;
        b2 = a2;
    }
    else // Removed the else if here since an else works
    {
        b1 = a2;
        b2 = a1;
    }

    for (i = b1; i <= b2; i++)
    {
      // Change =* to *=
      a3 *= i;
    }

    cout << "The series product of ";
    cout << a1 << ", " << a2 << ", "; 
    cout << " is: " << a3 << endl;

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @SidS Good catch, didn't think on that. Fixed. :)

Comment: Please use string-literal-concatenation instead of Breaking the column-limit. It's easier on any reader ;-)